# Upload file to Slack using the slack sdk for java

Tags: java, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a file to slack using the [slack sdk for java](https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/web-api-basics) and the [file.upload method](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload)

I've tried using both .file() and .fileData() and I'm getting no errors in the console in fact nothing seems to print after either of these methods are called. I only get "All ok" and the message in slack when using the content("something") method.

Here is my code:

```
    File report = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\report.zip");
    
    if(!report.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Report Zip Doesnt Exist");
        return false;
    }
    
    FilesUploadRequest request = FilesUploadRequest.builder()
            .channels(channels)
            .initialComment(comment)
            .filename(report.getName())
            //.file(report) doesnt work
            //.fileData(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(report)) doesnt work
            .content("something") // works
            .title("Report")
            .filetype("zip")
            .build();

    try {
        FilesUploadResponse response = methods.filesUpload(request);
        if (response.isOk()) {
            System.out.println("All ok");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println(response.getError());
            return false;
        }
    } catch (SlackApiException requestFailure) {
        System.out.println("Request failed");
        return false;
    } catch (IOException connectivityIssue) {
        System.out.println("Connectivity issue");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way

Create your app in slack ->
Go to Add features and functionality -> go to permission ->
Go to scopes -> Bot Token Scopes -> Add Oauth scope with files.write -> token generated

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.setBearerAuth(token); // pass generated token here
MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
bodyMap.add("file", bos.toByteArray(),fileName )); // convert file to ByteArrayOutputStream and pass with toByteArray() or pass with new File() 
bodyMap.add("initial_comment", message); // pass comments with file 
bodyMap.add("channels", "XXXXXX"); // pass channel codeID
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);
ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://slack.com/api/files.upload", entity,
            Object.class);
System.out.println("sendEmailWithAttachment() response status: "+ responseEntity.getStatusCode().toString());
```